# Module for sending messages through PubNub

Tags: php, json, drupal, pubnub

I have created a Drupal 6 module that sends messages through PubNub when the user updates information about a Node. I have a separate app that, when launched, calls my Drupal site and receives a JSON array containing a lot of information about some nodes. I then update the info in my other app by PubNub->publish from Drupal every time the page is reloaded after the Node is updated. I have the following in my `foo.module` file:

hook_admin: //not really a hook

```
function moduleName_admin(){
  //Here we are pulling in the Pubnub.php file from the module directory
  // NOTE: This file requires PubnubAES.php even when you aren't using encryption so include it too
  module_load_include('php', 'moduleName', 'Pubnub'); 
  $pubnub = new Pubnub( 
    "PUBKEY",
    "SUBKEY",
    "",
    false
  );
  $form = array();
  $query = "SELECT info FROM tables;"

  $results = db_query($query);

  while($r=db_fetch_object($results)){
    $form['moduleName_fieldDescription_'.$r->nid] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => "Select one for ".$r->info.":",
    '#options' => array(
      t('Foo'),
      t('Bar'),
      t('Baz')
    ),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('moduleName_fieldDescription_'.$r->nid, '0'),
  );

    $pubnub->publish(array(
      'channel' => 'channelName',
      'message' => array("id"=>$r->nid, "selected"=>variable_get('moduleName_fieldDescription_'.$r->nid, '0'))
    ));
  }
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

JSON page:

```
function moduleName_JSON(){
  $query = "SELECT info FROM table;"
  $results = db_query($query);

  $infoObject = array();
  for($i=0;$r = db_fetch_object($results); $i++){
    $infoObject[$i] = array(
      'info' => $r->info,
      'id' => $r->nid,
      'selected' => variable_get('moduleName_fieldDescription_'.$r->nid, '0'),
    );
  }
  //This next part will wrap the JSON in a function so jQuery can be called like 
  //$.ajax( {
    //url:"example.com/moduleName/json", 
    //dataType: 'jsonp', 
    //callback: 'foo', 
    //success:function(data){
      //checkListInfo = data;
      //styleSheetLoaded();
    //}
  //} );
  $callback = check_plain($_REQUEST['callback']); 
  if (isset($callback) && $callback != '') {
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    echo $callback ."(";
    drupal_json($infoObject);
    echo ");";
  } else {
    drupal_json($infoObject);
  }
}
```

hook_menu:

```
function moduleName_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['moduleName/editPage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Module edit page',
    'description' => 'Edit this page to make changes to pubnub',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('moduleName_admin'),
    'access arguments' => array('Edit moduleName Permissions'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['moduleName/json'] = array(
    'title' => 'JSON Array containing module info',
    'page callback' => 'moduleName_JSON',
    'access arguments' => array('Change moduleName values'),
    'tpye' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

This is slightly changed up code from my working Drupal 6 module that uses a live PubNub account. It works great for my purpose. I just want to know how to do it a little more to Drupal standards.

I know I probably have the publish time wrong. Right now it publishes when the page is reloaded instead of right before the page sends the info. I don't think this is right but I am very new to Drupal.

There is a Drupal Module that is in the process of being built that will allow PubNubs integration in Drupal 7/8 but I am on D6 and I am just including the files myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving the data you expect, I think you are 99% there.

Alternatively, you could include the PubNub JS client into your Drupal app (vs. the PHP client), then you can publish asynchronously, or even completely after page load.

[Link to the JS client and docs are available here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/javascript-sdk.html), with a [specific example of how to publish here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/data-push.html#publish)

Comment: I thought about this but I don't really have a reason to publish the message before the form is submitted and it is easier to do the PHP pubnub because it is server-side and doesn't rely on the client-side javascript. Also it would be kinda tricky to implement because of the way Drupal forms are generated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Surely! And if you have any additional PubNub-specific questions, feel free to ping us at support@pubnub.com, we're here to help.

Comment: Could you give some code examples to *show* the OP how to do something?  That would garner an up-vote from me.

Comment: @syb0rg please clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I'd need a more specific example of exactly what you'd be looking for an example of... need a use case, etc @syb0rg

Comment: @Geremy Give a link to the JS client in your answer, and maybe include an example for publishing asynchronously/after page load.